# Delete existing Image before create new Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, bitmap

Hi i have the following Function:

```
  private void CreateRoomImage(string path)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    var file = "";



    foreach (PanelView panelView in pv)
    {
        var RoomImage = GetRaumImageName(panelView.Title);
        file = path + GetImageFile(RoomImage);

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        using (var img = GetRaumImage(panelView.Title, panelView))
        {

            ImageWriter imgWriter = new ImageWriter(ImageFormat.Bmp);
            imgWriter.Save(img, file);

        }



    }

}
```

My Problem is that everytime i try to Delete the existing File my programm is throwing an exception:

```
The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Is there a solution for this Problem? How can i delete the existing image?

Comment: What code is in `GetRaumImage`?

Comment: On this line: file = path + GetImageFile(RoomImage);

What is 'RoomImage'? I see no declaration...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this could be a weird race condition where the file.exists hasn't released the resource and it is trying to delete prior to release. I would probably try something along these lines.

```
    try
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
    catch
    {
       //File does not exist or another error occurred.
    }
```

Comment: This just means an error won't be raised, it doesn't mean the file will be deleted ...

Answer (score 0):

I found it on my Own.

In PageLoad i use thet "file" also. I forgot to dispose the Image:

```
 foreach (PanelView panel in pv)
    {

        path = Request.PhysicalPath.Substring(0, Request.PhysicalPath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + subPath + "\\" + GetRaumImageName(panel.Title);
        bitMap = new Bitmap(path + ".bmp");

        b0 = BmpToMonochromConverter.CopyToBpp(bitMap, 1);

       // bounce.updateInterface.UpdateProductImage(b0, panel.Panel.PRODUCT_ID, "", ref update_Handle);
        bitMap.Dispose();
    }
```

Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: This is why you post *everything*, not just snippets - we had no chance in diagnosing your problem because the issue was in code you **didn't show us**.

Answer (score 0):

Why delete file in the first place? Can't you make it overwrite the existing file if it already exists?

Another thing you can do is to pause the thread for like 400ms until OS does it's thing and files are completely deleted and all streams closed.